# Расшифрвока по приватному ключу / Аналог JSEncrypt для C#

Tags: c#, .net, rsa

Вынужден переводить кусок кода с JS на C#, и наткнулся там на такой вот момент:

```
var decrypt = new JSEncrypt();
decrypt.setPrivateKey("Здесь Base64-строка, представляющая приватный ключ");
var result = decrypt.decrypt("Здесь Base64-строка, представляющая зашифрованный текст");
```

И что-то никак не могу найти чего-то настолько же компактного в родном `.NET`: все стандартные инструменты просят ключ в `xml`-формате, для создания которого требуется вытянуть из строки ключа определенные данные (`modulus`, `exponent` etc)...

---

В общем, вопрос таков: какие инструменты можно использовать, чтобы расшифровать текст по приватному ключу в `Base64`-формате?

Comment: Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt) на указанную библиотеку, которая используется в js-коде

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, помогла мне следующая чудесная библиотека - [BouncyCastle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/)

Код вышел довольно простой и короткий:

```
private static string DecryptText(string Base64Text, string PrivateKey, Encoding Encoding)
{
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair;
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader($"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n{PrivateKey}\r\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----")) // file containing RSA PKCS1 private key
        keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();

    Pkcs1Encoding decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
    decryptEngine.Init(false, keyPair.Private);

    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64Text);
    return Encoding.GetString(decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
}
```

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь сие тоже когда-нибудь пригодится)